# Laravel 5.3: как убрать редирект на /login для гостей

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Есть контроллер HomeController с функцией `Index`, которая отображает у меня главную страницу сайта. В этот же контроллер я добавил:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

При этом, если на сайт заходит гость, то его редиректит на форму входа `/login`.
А мне нужно, чтобы этот редирект не происходил. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это поправить.

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Смысл в этих действиях такой, что вы хотите, чтобы главная страница по-разному отображалась для залогиненных и незалогиненных пользователей, верно?

Comment: Нет. Смысл в том, что сейчас если гость заходит на главную страницу сайта или же любую страницу где подключен `$this->middleware('auth');` его редиректит на страницу входа, а мне нужно чтобы он мог просматривать эти страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так удали middleware или исключи index с помощью except.
[Controller Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#controller-middleware)

Comment: Если удаляю или исключаю, то при вызове Auth::user() получаю ошибку - http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_136kb.1486297292.png

Comment: Я так понимаю, что где-то можно отключить этот редирект, т.е. чтобы и middleware был подключен, но при этом просто редирект не сробатывал. Но вот не могу найти где и как правильно это сделать.

Comment: Все, я понял в чем проблема была. Нужно было действительно удалить middleware, я просто думал что без него  не смогу потом получить данные о пользователе. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Просто закомментируй или удали конструктор.

Comment: Постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы.